# Including both chapter name and name of section in header using memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I'm writing a thesis using `memoir` as my class. I would like a header **similar to `fancyhdr`**, but this is not emulated in `memoir`. I know how to make my own pagestyle, however when I try to refer to the chapter name it only prints the chapter number.
On verso pages, I want the chapter name to be left ragged and the section name to be right ragged, and vice versa on recto pages. My code looks like this:

```
    \makepagestyle{dtu}
    \makeevenhead{dtu}{\sffamily \thechapter}{}{\sffamily \thesection}
    \makeoddhead{dtu}{\sffamily \thesection}{}{\sffamily \thechapter}
    \makeevenfoot{dtu}{\sffamily \thepage}{}{}
    \makeoddfoot{dtu}{}{}{\sffamily\thepage}
    \makeheadrule{dtu}{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \pagestyle{dtu}
```

But it only prints the numbers, not the number + name of the chapter/section! **How can I include the number+name of each chapter and section in the header?**

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\leftmark`/`\rightmark` instead of `\thechapter`/`\thesection`. See p. 120 of the `memoir` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{dtu}
\makeevenhead{dtu}{\sffamily\leftmark}{}{\sffamily\rightmark}
\makeoddhead{dtu}{\sffamily\rightmark}{}{\sffamily\leftmark}
\makeevenfoot{dtu}{\sffamily\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{dtu}{}{}{\sffamily\thepage}
\makeheadrule{dtu}{\textwidth}{1pt}
\pagestyle{dtu}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: ha may need to set the chapter and section marks as well if they are much different than the default, hence the reference to my article.

Comment: Tak for din artikel, Lars. Jeg har også hentet din bog. Dit arbejde er meget værdsat :-)