# Identical marks in header with onesided memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, header-footer, memoir

I'm using memoir for an onesided document, but I wanted to have both the chapter and section numbers and names in the header.

I'm using this to achieve it (from [Including both chapter name and name of section in header using memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78141/including-both-chapter-name-and-name-of-section-in-header-using-memoir))

```
\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeoddhead{ruled}{\sffamily\leftmark}{}{\sffamily\rightmark}
```

This works great most of the time, however for the ToC and bibliography, both of which are two pages long, I have the same label twice in the header, which looks terrible.

I would like to only show the `\rightmark` if it's different from the `\leftmark`. Or somehow change the labeling of those two things. For example it works OK in introduction, which is an `\unnumberedchapter` and has no `\section`. I've tried changing `\bibsection` to `\unnumberedchapter` but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm beginning to think that for any question, there's always an answer inspired by egreg ([On testing two fully expanded character strings for equality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59565/on-testing-two-fully-expanded-character-strings-for-equality)):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59565/on-testing-two-fully-expanded-character-strings-for-equality
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\test}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=\z@ \relax \else #2 \fi
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{ruled}
\makeoddhead{ruled}{\sffamily\leftmark}{}{\sffamily\test{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\makechapter}{
\chapter{foo}
\section{foobar}
\lipsum[1-12]
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter
\makechapter

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I give good inspirations, it seems. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Good solutions too. And at times good lessons, criticisms ..... :).

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I tried something like this but didn't properly expand the macros before comparison which didn't work so I gave up on that idea.

Comment: Proper use of `\expandafter` has always been a sticking point for me, too. I'll certainly go for this method in the future.