# custom headers that use chapter titles

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I have been unable to find the a way to get the current chapter title for use in a custom header.

I have roughly:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeoddhead{myheadings}{}{\thechapter}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{myheadings}{\thepage}{...}{}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

but I want the chapter name instead of chapter number

Comment: Use `\leftmark` instead of `\thechapter`. Related or duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78141/120578

Comment: Also, if you want to get rid of the chapter number you may use something like : `\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{\space}`

Comment: @koleygr`\leftmark` doesn't seem to place any text

Comment: @koleygr sorry my last message didn't at you.  \leftmark doesn't seem to place any text I feel like I need to redefine the `\chaptermark` macro but am not sure how